# How do I fix Mayavi contour3d?

Tags: mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I've used Mayavi 3d contour before and it was working fine, but when I tried it recently on a new machine, it doesn't seem to work as supposed to. It looks as if the depth was inverted.

To illustrate the example, here is a comparison of a 3D Gabor function plotted with `contour3d` and what the plot lookes like on my new machine (left) and old machine (right).

[image]

So basically the inner-most values are displayed as if they were outer.

The current mayavi version I have is 4.6.2 and vtk 8.1.2. I've downgraded to 4.5.0 and 8.1.0 respectively, but the same issue occurs. I am not really sure where else to look, so appreciate any help!

Edit: The same issue happens with `volume_slice` function (the planes do not overlap, but oddly render in front of one another):

[image]

Code example:

```
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as mb

x, y, z = np.ogrid[-5:5:64j, -5:5:64j, -5:5:64j]
scalars = x * x * 0.5 + y * y + z * z * 2.0
mb.volume_slice(scalars, plane_orientation='y_axes')
mb.volume_slice(scalars, plane_orientation='x_axes')
mb.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a short code example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Edited to include a code for reproduction now.

Not sure if you can reproduce it though. This code has worked perfectly on my other workstation, but not the new one, so I suspect it has something to do with versions or dependencies, but not quite sure where to look

Comment: @jolaem have you ever been able to solve this issue? I have it on my current machine (the only one I've ever tried mayavi on) and it's driving me crazy

Comment: @Alf Not really, but my notes say that swapping the x and y axis the problem was mitigated enough to make the thing usable. Not used much since my comment though, so I don't recall the details

Comment: @Davide thanks for answering, and mitigating is fine for me at the moment :)